# More realistic perspective algorithms

Tags: algorithm, opengl, 3d

As I noticed, many 3D games (almost all, I think) use simple algorithm for computing perspective. It works almost ideal, but all objects significantly deform at the edges of the FOV. The sipliest example of this effect is the fact that all spheres at the edges of FOV look not like circles.
The OpenGl function `gluPerspective()` creates perspective with same defect.

I have a rough idea of better algorithm that, as I think, will fix this problem.

So, question is:
Is there any algorithms that don't have this defect and where I can read about them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any algorithms that don't have this defect and where I can read about them?

There are several: Spherical projections, Stereographic projections. Cylindrical projections. Tiled panoramic projections, and so on, you name it.

Rastering systems that are based on triangles however have a very important requirement on the projection to work properly: Straight lines must be projection into to straight lines (affine projection). This is the cause for the unpleasant distortions you see. Any of the projections I mentioned above (and many more) can be approximated with OpenGL using an appropriate vertex shader. However to look good the geometry must be sufficiently fine tesselated, because straight edges need to be broken down into sufficiently many segments to allow mapping to curves. A tesselation shader can be used for this. Another approach is rendering a wide field view into a cube map (cube maps require an affine projection for their creation). Then you can apply and other mapping on the cubemap, which leads to more robust results.